# How to get an image response in OpenApi Swagger 3.0

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an endpoint which returns an image in response and I would like the swagger documentation to return and display the image within the framework.
I've looked at the documentation [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) and [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/media-types/) and tried all three examples all which have no success.
Am I trying the impossible?

Here is my example

```
paths:
   "/qrcodes/{string_to_encode}":
    get:
      tags:
        - QR Code
      summary: A QR code generation endpoint
      parameters:
        - name: string_to_encode
          in: path
          required: true
          description: URL encoded string to convert to a QR code
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
              application/png:
                schema: 
                  type: string
                  format: binary
```

The generated curl also warns about binary output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `application/png` to `image/png`. Other than that, your definition is correct.